# Как ставить знаки препинания, если мы даём дополнение, а за ним определение к нему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, грамматика, тире

> "Такая реклама заинтересует наших читателей - молодых мам"

Или вот такой пример

> "Я люблю родной край - место плясок и песен"

Comment: Как native Russian speaker не вижу в обоих примерах никакой ошибки / недочёта. А какие могли бы быть варианты? Вроде как, лучше и не поставишь пунктуацию. Разве что точку в конце, но она сама собой очевидна[,] и вопрос не о ней ) Спасибо.

Comment: Можно поставить запятую при обособлении приложения, но по Розенталю нужно ставить тире, пункт 10 (1) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111